# JavaScript code to reformat text based on the desired character length per line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, typography

Re,

I'm looking for vanilla JavaScript (or a jQuery plugin) code that would calculate the number of text characters on each line inside a `div` element and reformat the text by limiting characters per line to a certain number.

I'm using a Zurb Foundation grid and I believe the font size and column width are all dynamic.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Wrapping text based on character length is considerably easier than pixel-line-length with varying letter sizes (non monospaced fonts).

Comment: Depending on the screen size, the div can be 1000px or 300px H. word-wrap property doesn't help since I have to specify the width and the font can be of different size. I need the text to wrap exactly at 60 or 70 characters regardless of the size of the parent element and the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function that would reformat the text into whatever character limit you want to specify and insert breaks inbetween, but it doesn't take tags into account at all.

```
function wrap(str, limit) {
    var len = str.length,
        output = [];

    for(var i=0;i*limit < len;i++) {
        output.push(str.substring(i*limit, limit);
    }

    return output.join('<br>');
}
```